# Linux cron job to email output from a command

Tags: linux, email, cron, output-redirect

I would like to run a cron job to backup some mysql databases by piping the output to a file and then emailing it.

Will the following work?

```
15 2 * * * root mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --all-databases | \
    gzip > /database_`data'+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz | \
    mail -s "Report 05/06/07" user@example.com < /database_`data'+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your script, I have altered it below, note carefully the change of spaces, spelling of `date` and replacement of `|` for `;`.

The most interesting problem however is that `mail` unfortunately can't send attachments.  You could use uuencode to embed the file in the mail using:

```
15 2 * * * root mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --all-databases | gzip > /database_`date +'%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz ; uuencode /database_`date +'%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz /dev/stdout | mail -s "Report 05/06/07" user@domain.com
```

Or if you want to have a proper MIME attachment use (You will need MetaMail installed):

```
15 2 * * * root mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --all-databases | gzip > /database_`date +'%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz ; metasend -b -t user@domain.com -s "Report 05/06/07" -m application/gzip -f /database_`date +'%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz
```

Or as above with mpack installed, instead of MetaMail:

```
15 2 * * * root mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --all-databases | gzip > /database_`date +'%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz ; mpack -s "Report 05/06/07" -c application/gzip /database_`date +'%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz user@domain.com
```

Comment: i like the second one, but I cannot find a single way to install metamail under centos... all packages I find atm are "not found" or refuse to compile... :(

Comment: @renevdkooi I don't know much about centos unfortunately.  I have updated the answer with an example using mpack, you could give that a go instead.

Comment: You can also use `mutt` which supports MIME attachments (`-a` option) and is readily available on Centos/RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the first option but had an error, with a small modification it worked fine:

```
15 2 * * * root mysqldump -e --user=root --password=PASSWORD --all-databases | gzip | uuencode `date +'%Y%m%d'`-database.sql.gz | mail -s "`date +'%Y%m%d'`-web1_iepe-wp.sql.gz mysqldump backup" user@domain.com
```

Tks!