# Linux crontab find and email results receiving EOF

Tags: linux, email, cron

when I run a command via command line, it works fine, I get the email with the desired results inside of an attached *.txt file. however, when cron runs this same command, I receive an EOF error.

Can anyone point out what might be causing this error?

I am running CPanel on CentOS with Cloudlinux 6.6

Here is the email I receive from cron saying it errored;

```
Subject: Cron <root@whm> find /home/accountname/public_html -type f -mtime -7 2> `date +'

/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is my command;

```
01 * * * * find /home/accountname/public_html -type f -mtime -7 2> `date +'%m-%d-%Y'`-accountname-filescan.txt | uuencode `date +'%m-%d-%Y'`-accountname-filescan.txt | mail -s "`date +'%m-%d-%Y'`-accountname File Scan Report" root
```

I'd appreciate any constructive input on what I am doing wrong.

I followed this thread to develop my command;
[Linux cron job to email output from a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190215/linux-cron-job-to-email-output-from-a-command)

Comment: `cron` runs as a different user, so the `/home/accountname/`... will not be pointing where you think it is. Also, if you are using `mailx` as `mail` it contains the `-a` option to allow you to attach the file rather than `uuencode` and pipe to the message. Check if you have the option available (e.g. `mail -s "..." -a $(date +'%m-%d-%Y')-accountname-filescan.txt`)

Comment: I think with something that long, you would be better off putting all that it in a file, say `/usr/local/etc/file-scan-report` and then just have `01 * * * * /usr/local/etc/file-scan-report` in crontab.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I tried to use the `mail -a` option you mentioned and it caused some strange results to say the least - I did discover that I don't need to `uuencode` though. thanks for suggesting that. ;)

Comment: @JohnHascall thanks for that suggestion I implemented a script today and its much easier editing the script than editing a super long cron entry! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape %:

```
man (5) crontab:

Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), 
will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the 
first % will be sent to the command as standard input.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! DOH! ;)